# Does Adjusted Closing Price take account the Expense Ratio?

Tags: equities, returns, python, etf, yahoofinance

first time posting at Quantitative Finance.

I am trying to use the yfinance python library to load various ETF's data and compared the return.

I understand the adjusted closing price handles the effect of dividend and stock split. I wonder in the case of ETF or mutual fund, does the adjusted closed price takes care of the expense ratio? I tried to Google but got no definite answer.

If not, what is the best way to deal with the effect of expense ratio on return?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to back out the expense ratio manually.  The expenses are deducted from the ETF NAV and baked into the price of the ETFs.

From the link below:

> **You won't find them on your account statement**
>
> The cost of investing is usually associated with trading commissions
> and account service fees—items you see as "debits" from your accounts.
>
> But expense ratios are less obvious because they're not itemized on
> your account statements or confirmations. Instead, each fund's
> expenses are deducted from its total value on a regular basis. And
> those expenses cut directly into your investment returns.

[Expense ratios: What they are & how they work](https://investor.vanguard.com/expense-ratio/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With that being said, the adjusted closing price that we downloaded from Yahoo can be used directly without additional consideration of the expense ratio.

Comment: @Porkbun-Wei Yes, that's correct.